# iOS Image Gallery scrolling horizontally

Tags: ios

Hi I want to create an image gallery where you can slide left and right to see them. I was wondering what is the best way to do this or if there are any existant libraries I can use. I have attached an image of what I want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). They have a demo version of it. check it first before using it

Answer (score 3):

`UICollectionView` is the answer for your question ,you can easily manage as many images as you want in the `UICollectionView`, please refer to the following link :

http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for native iOS a page control object is exactly what you are looking for